# Symfony2 and doctrine2 entity manager not found in cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, cache-control, symfony-2.1

Since symfony 2.1.1 upgrade my server gives the following error on accessing the domain on any url:

```
Fatal error: Class 'EM5056f1cdb2579_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\
__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' not found in /home/<host>/<site>
/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 115
```

Clearing the (prod) cache helps, but this happens daily after the cronjob - what could this be? My cronjob does run with `--env=prod`

Comment: Could it be related to APC ? Do you use the APC Class Loader ?

Comment: No accelerator is enabled on the server.

Comment: Are you running `cache:clear` with the `--no-debug` option in addition to the `--env=prod` option?

Comment: The problem was the cron jobs that ran with `--env=prod` was causing the error. It works now that I've removed it, but I'm sure that cron jobs should have the environment set?